# Error with Python in Install of opencv in Ubuntu 14.04,

Tags: python, opencv

the Error message is

```
[ 92%] Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/cv2.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/cv2.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

if someone have any ideal about it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to build using a Python install that's not provided by the system? It seems like it since it's trying to link to a python library in `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: I have reinstalled Python ,then it works. Thanks!